# How can I access the System Account in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

I have always wanted to have access to the system account in Windows 7 – on a test machine, not my regular use machine.

In Windows XP it is easy, there are how-to's all over the internet. How can I wield the power of the system account in Windows 7? It has to be possible, I just don't think people have actively/knowingly discovered how yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `psexec` from Sysinternals as mentioned in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78691/435093):

> [...] I came across this [article](http://verbalprocessor.com/2007/12/05/running-a-cmd-prompt-as-local-system) which demonstrates the use of [PSTools](http://download.sysinternals.com/Files/PsTools.zip) from [SysInternals](http://sysinternals.com/) (which was acquired by Microsoft in July, 2006.) I launched the command line via the following and suddenly I was running under the Local Admin Account like magic:
>
> ```
> psexec -i -s cmd.exe
> ```
>
> PSTools worked great.  It's a lightweight, well-documented set of tools which, in my opinion, provide an appropriate solution to my problem.